# Efficient way of mapping / casting byte array to object

Tags: c#, casting

I have a list with objects that describe on which offset and length the value is on the byte array, for example I have a object with a property for offset which is 4 and a byte length of 1, so when I receive `019 019 016 021 032 024 255 255` the value of the object needs to be set to 21.

Anyone have a good solution for doing this on a efficient way?

Sample on how I am doing it right now:

```
 public static void CallBackOnMessage(byte[] msg, int msgLength)
    {
        bool updates = false;
        byte[] Message = msg;
        JArray jso2n = new JArray();

        foreach (Tag tag in _tagHandler.tagList)
        {
            if(tag.addressingByteLength == 1)
            {
                byte value = msg[tag.addressingByte];
                string tagValue = value.ToString();

                if(tagValue != null)
                {
                    jso2n.Add(new JObject(
                    new JProperty("meta",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("identifier", tag.id)
                        )
                    ),
                    new JProperty("data",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("value", tagValue)
                        )
                    )));
                    updates = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[tag.addressingByteLength];
                Array.Copy(msg, tag.addressingByte, bytes, 0, tag.addressingByteLength);
            }

        }
        if (updates)
        {
            var jsonString = jso2n.ToString();
            cocosApi.patch("system", "taglist", null, null, null, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString), _deviceID);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Comment: What does this have to with "casting"?  What is being cast to what?  What does "the value of the object needs to be..." mean?

Comment: If you just want to copy a range from your array to another byte array then Buffer.BlockCopy(), if your asking how to copy a range of bytes to a specific type then your going to need to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: Sounds like de-serialisation to me.

Comment: @phuzi something like that Indeed..

Comment: @ErwinVorenhout could you at least write some pseudo code to illustrate what you mean. It's not very clear and without more information your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Lets not stop at the trivial example... what would be the expected result for offset `0`? What would be the expected result for offset `4` byte length `2`? And most importantly: __why?__ If you don't explain the reasoning why your example input produces the example output, the answer might well be "just set the value to 21 statically".